# A question about the set of pairs $(x,y)$ such that $0<x<y<p/2$ and $p\mid x^2+y^2$ for a fixed prime number $p$

Tags: number-theory

Like the title, fix a prime $p$. Consider the pairs of integers $(x,y)$ such that
$$
x^2+y^2=0 \bmod p \quad x \leq y \leq (p-1)/2.
$$

I find some property

1. $p$ needs to be $4k+1$
2. There exists an element $a$ such that $a^2=-1$
3. The sum of all set $y$ is twice as large as the sum of all set $x$

for example:$\mathbb Z_{13} $

$1^2+5^2=0$ mod $p$,

$2^2+3^2=0$ mod $p$ ,

$4^2+6^2=0$ mod $p$

then $(1+2+4)\cdot 2=5+3+6$

I know the 1) 2) is about Euler Criterion, but I have no idea about 3).

Please give me some hint for 3). Thanks.

Comment: An unrelated but fun Q: If $p$ is prime and $p\ge 11$ and $1\le n\le p-1$ then there are $x,y$ with $n\equiv x^2+y^2 \pmod p$ and $0\not\equiv x^2 \not\equiv y^2 \not\equiv 0\pmod p$.

Comment: This seems to be an interesting problem. For all $n$ ,it only exist only one set of solution with $x \leq y \leq (p-1)/2$, and it seems that the frequency of numbers is regular.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**A hint as requested - not a full proof**

Consider a pair $(x,y)$ satisfying your opening condition.

Then $(y-x)^2+(y+x)^2=0\mod p$ and $(y-x)^2+(p-y-x)^2=0\mod p$.

Note that  $y-x<y+x$ and $y-x<p-y-x$. We can then choose whichever of $y+x$ and $p-y-x$ is less than or equal to $(p-1)/2$.

We have therefore constructed a pair $(x-y,*)$ satisfying your opening condition.

Now let $X,Y,D$ be the sets of $x,y,y-x$, respectively, such that $(x,y)$ satisfies your opening condition. The above argument suggests that $X$ and $D$ are the same sets and then property 3 will automatically hold.

**Example**

You can see the $X=D$ result in your example, where both sets consist of $1,2,4$.

Comment: OH!!I got your hint .Thanks.

Comment: Great. this is a nice problem - did you spot it or was it an exercise?

Comment: From  exploratory exercises given by my professor.

Comment: Very good! Its quite a surprising result since the way numbers x and y pair up so their sums of squares is 0 seems quite 'random'.